# SOAP request payload

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I have a webservice where request payload is as follows

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:poc="http://www.poc.mbo.demo.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <poc:doTransaction>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <dealerid>1</dealerid>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <partid>1</partid>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <quantity>2</quantity>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <orderdate>12-DEC-2012</orderdate>
  </poc:doTransaction>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But if i try like this its giving no response. what could be the issue

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:poc="http://www.poc.mbo.demo.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <poc:doTransaction>
     <!--Optional:-->
      <poc:dealerid>1</poc:dealerid>
      <!--Optional:-->
     <poc:partid>1</poc:partid>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <quantity>2</quantity>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <poc:orderdate>12-DEC-2012</poc:orderdate>
  </poc:doTransaction>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you post the error ?

Answer (score 0):

The `doTransaction` elements in the first sample are not in the `http://www.poc.mbo.demo.com` namespace.

Your request either fails validation (assuming validation is enabled) or the server ignores the invalid elements and treats the request as being equivalent to:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
    xmlns:poc="http://www.poc.mbo.demo.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <poc:doTransaction />
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the WSDL of ur service the element  would have assosiated with a namespace (a XSD), but the others may be part of another namespace (XSD),

To understand that clearly just check the WSDL the type section and the operation , check which type(Element) is assciated with which XSD.. u can easily understand y it is failing..

Think namespace as imported class and type as it's one of the state(:) Just for easy understanding)